# batch commands not working in the script

Tags: batch-file, command

I am still relatively new to batch scripts. I am trying to write a script to execute some matlab commands, essentially run a matlab script on a 32 bit version and a 64 bit version from Windows 7.

When i run the commands in the DOS prompt, everything works as i expect, but when they are run as a script, i get an error message saying that the system cannot find the path specified

script.bat

```
@echo off

set RESTORE=restoredefaultpath
set HOMEDIRECTORY=P:\ISARLAB\IsarLab-Dev
set SCRIPTNAME=packageScript
set MATLABCOMMAND="%RESTORE%; cd %HOMEDIRECTORY%; %SCRIPTNAME%"

echo launching Matlab 32 bit ...

::32 bit Matlab on Windows
set MATLAB32BIT="C:\Prorgram Files\MATLAB\R2012b-32bit\bin\matlab.exe"
echo %MATLAB32BIT% -r %MATLABCOMMAND%
%MATLAB32BIT% -r %MATLABCOMMAND%


@echo on
```

output from script:

```
launching Matlab 32 bit ...
"C:\Prorgram Files\MATLAB\R2012b-32bit\bin\matlab.exe" -r "restoredefaultpath; cd P:\ISARLAB\IsarLab-Dev; packageScript"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I have confirmed that the path specified is correct and the correct version of Matlab is launched when this .exe is executed.

commands run at dos prompt (this works):

```
set RESTORE=restoredefaultpath
set HOMEDIRECTORY=P:\ISARLAB\IsarLab-Dev
set SCRIPTNAME=packageScript
set MATLABCOMMAND="%RESTORE%; cd %HOMEDIRECTORY%; %SCRIPTNAME%"
set MATLAB32BIT="C:\Prorgram Files\MATLAB\R2012b-32bit\bin\matlab.exe"
%MATLAB32BIT% -r %MATLABCOMMAND%
```

Can someone explain why the commands work in the dos prompt but not in a script?

Comment: There is no such folder as `C:\Prorgram Files`. Check your spelling of `Program`. Neither the batch file or the command line version will work with that spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line below have an error:

```
set MATLAB32BIT="C:\Prorgram Files\MATLAB\R2012b-32bit\bin\matlab.exe"
```

should be "Program", not "Prorgram".

**EDIT:** Oops! I did not read Ken White's comment before posting my answer! I apologize...